# Web page built in HTML being different in Handlebars

Tags: css, express, handlebars.js

So, I have built a signup form with HTML, CSS and Javascript for using it in a Express server with Handlebars as view engine. But when I took the code from the page to the Handlebars file, the page got different for some reason.

This is what the page looks like in the HTML local file
[Print local HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5l6j.png)

And this is what the page looks like in the server with Handlebars
[Print local server Handlebars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMhQb.png)

I did not change the code while taking it from HTML and putting into Handlebars

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for someone to help you. It looks like some of your CSS rules aren't being applied to your migrated code. Assuming the CSS has all been migrated and is loading on the page, maybe there is a CSS-selector specificity issue that is preventing some rules from applying. I would advise you to use the browser's dev tools to compare the CSS applied in the working version vs the broken version and, from there, try to understand what is causing the difference.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.